# How to make a relatively positioned child to get all parent's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this layout

```css
body, html {
  height: 90%;
}
#content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
#sidebar-content {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
  
}
#sidebar-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
#main-content {
   height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-content">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="main-content">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I need the sidebar to occupy all height available if it's height lower than the #main's. Setting the sidebar position to absolute solves this, but adding even more bugs, is there a solution for the relatively positioned child to get all the parent's height **without** specifying height of the parent in pixels?

As you can see in the fiddle, if #main exceeding the sidebar's width the sidebar is shorter, but it need to fill all the height.

Comment: Please give us fidddle link.

Comment: what 'bugs' does it give?

Comment: @jbutler483 if #sidebar is absolute it's contents will squeeze to the height of the #main

Answer (score 0):

I guess jQuery solution will help you solve your problem :) [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/g280tqa8/) This will allow to have the `#sidebar` to have same height as the `container`. Hope this helps :) Happy coding.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapH = $('#content').outerHeight();

    $('#sidebar').css("height", wrapH);
});
```

Edited:

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/g280tqa8/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapH = $('#main').outerHeight();

    $('#sidebar').css("height", wrapH);
});
```

Just change the content to main. Hope this solves the issue. This will make the sidebar height be the same as the main height.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, your solution works indeed, but I can't use javascript because it will cause a bug while page loads.

I will add a fiddle, so that you could see

Comment: @royhowie Noted Sir. sorry for that. I was too lazy to include those in my answer

Comment: @user3223824 Oh I see. Okay post some fiddle hope I can give some solution on what you really need :)

Comment: I added a fiddle, hope it'll be easier.

Comment: I've updated my answer also my fiddle. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Flexbox does indeed solve your problem, and is the perfect answer if you don't have to support older browsers.

Basically, just adding `display: flex` to the container will sort this out for you.

Browsers support flexbox in a variety of ways, make sure you check the compiled CSS of that Pen to get all the browser pre-fixes and such.

[Link to CodePen](http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/zGBdPo)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a combination of css properties to achieve what you are looking for. The main reason you were running into trouble with the `position:absolute` was due to your `float:left`.

Have a glance through this and you may find some of the positioning and width declarations useful in your implementation:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 90%;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgray;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 8;
}
#sidebar-content {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#sidebar-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#main {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
#main-content {}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-content">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="main-content">this is the main content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```